# ArgumentNullException on ReadXML

Tags: c#, dataset, xml-serialization, argumentnullexception, readxml

I have a problem with my DataSet serialization to XML file. Every time I try to load the XML, the ReadXML() function throws the ArgumentNullException. What is interesting, this issue occurs only when I load it to the empty dataset. When I fill tables in my DataSet and then try to replace them loading DataSet from XML file, there is no Exception thrown. My DataTables are connected with relations. I do not use XMLScheme, because then my XML file never loads, even if I replace the existing dataset.

When the exception is thrown I have one table partly loaded: first record is loaded correctly and second one is filled by null values and StrongTypingExceptions.

Done anyone know what is going on ?

//edit:

Writing:

```
config.WriteXml(FileName,XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
```

Reading:

```
config.ReadXml(FileName,XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
```

I've tried all modes.

When schema is reading:

> [System.Data.DataException]   {"invalid 'key' node inside constraint:
>   FK_SapTable_SapFieldFilter."} System.Data.DataException

I have two tables connected by relation FK_SapTable_SapFieldFilter. In table "SapTable" i have field TableId as key - it is never null. It is connected to TableId field in SapFieldFilter. My SapFieldFilter is an empty table for now, but it shouldn't make a problem:

[My relation -> pic](http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/9469/beznazwy4v.png)

Comment: Try to load the Schema first so that dataset can apply the relations between the tables and then load the data into the tables.

Comment: Everytime I try to load XMLSchema i get exception:
"Invalid 'key' node inside constraint"

Comment: Did you try to use like this: `ds.ReadXml( "schema.xml", XmlReadMode.IgnoreSchema );`

Comment: Yes. I tried all modes both loading and saving.

Comment: you can post the inner exception and more details on the relations here for further analysis.